# Finding the limit of a function with sines and cosines by using the taylor expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, residue-calculus

I need to find the residue of a second order pole $z=0$, the residue works out to the following:

$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{2z\sin{z^2}-2z^3\cos{z^2}}{\text{sin}^2{z^2}}$$

My professor said it's possible by using the taylor series of the sine and cosine:

$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{2z(z^2-\frac{z^6}{3!}+\text{...})-2z^3(1-\frac{z^4}{2}+\text{...})}{(z^2-\frac{z^6}{3!}+\text{...})^2}$$

This, according to my professor, works out to:

$$= \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{\frac{2}{6}z^7-z^7+\text{H.O}}{z^4+\text{O}(z^8)}=0$$

I understand that the H.O. in the numerator are the terms of higher order and that they can be neglected. What I don't get is the O that is used in the denominator. Does it mean the same as H.O. and if so, how do you get to the $8$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is an entire even function, $\frac{\sin x}{x}=f(x^2)$ with $f$ entire, and $\frac{\sin x^2}{x^2}=f(x^4)$, so:
$$ \sin^2 x^2 = \left( x^2 f(x^4)\right)^2 = x^4 f^2(x^4) = g(x^4) $$
with $g$ entire.

Comment: I understand what is done here, but I don't understand what it implies for my original question unfortunately

Comment: @Joshua: If $g$ is entire and $g(z) = A + Bz + O(z^2)$, then $g(x^4) = A + B x^4 + O(x^8)$.

Comment: I still don't see it. I understand what you're doing in your original answer but not why. Why did you define that function as $g(x^4)$ and why did you define $g(z)$ the way you did?

Comment: To show that for any entire and even function $f$, $f^2(x^2) = A + Bx^4 + O(x^8)$ holds. It is the reason for the eight to appear.